# Effective timing, duration and intensity of exercise for work focus with ADHD

Tags: adhd, exercise

I read all over the place that exercise can provide dopamine, and can help reduce ADHD symptoms, but no source I have found mentions specifics.

My personal experience is if I work out at a moderate to high intensity for 20-30 minutes, I have more trouble sitting at my desk to work - I either want to move around, rest, or do something fun like play a game. This effect seems to last 60 minutes or more.

It is unclear whether the advice to exercise means to just get enough exercise each week, or exercise in the morning to give a benefit for the day, or multiple times a day if the main benefits on attention last less than 8 hours.

Is there more detailed information about exercise effects on ADHD symptoms or dopamine that includes intensity and timing of benefits, or a suggested exercise schedule to gain maximum benefit for a standard work or school week?

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE! I am sorry, but [for a number of reasons outlined in this meta post](https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/502/why-was-my-self-help-question-closed-as-off-topic) we can not, and will not, give advice or potential diagnoses for any specific individual. If you or anyone else has a question regarding personal mental health, advice from a doctor should be sought. For further information on how this site is supposed to work, what is on-topic or not, you can take the [tour], visit the [ask] page and [meta].

Comment: Welcome to psych.SE.  I disagree with @ChrisRogers - this does not sound like a self-help question to me, but a question about underlying research.  However, please provide links/references to what you have already read about the effect of exercise on ADHD symptoms.